# Why is my footer wider than rest of content?

Tags: bootstrap-4

[1. The top right it shows how much it goes back when I let go of the scroll and the bottom right shows how much the footer goes off to the right. It does not do the same for the left. Sorry for the content of the page. Just learning how to code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do3m6.png)Here is the code in bootstrap: I need this footer to stop extending off of the page whenever I scroll to the right.  The grey color I have set for it just keeps going a couple pixels off.  Thank you!

```
        <div id="footer" class="row justify-content-center">

            <h2>Download this app!</h2>

            <div class="col-md-12 bs-linebreak"></div>

                <p class="lead">Really, what are you waiting for?</p>

            <div class="col-md-12 bs-linebreak"></div>

                <p><a href=""><img id="getAppLogo" src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/app-store-logo-png/apple-app-store-travel-awards-globestamp-7.png"></a></p>

        </div>
```

Here is the css: I think this is where the problem is but I don't know what to addd or take away, if you would be kind enough to help out that would be great.

```css
        #footer {

            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #252A2C;
            margin-top: 50px;
            padding-top: 30px;
            padding-bottom: 30px;
            text-shadow: 6px 6px 6px black;

        }
```

Comment: can you share screenshot. Add your rest of content to see issue.

Comment: To be able to figure this out, we will need the context of the footer, so please share the whole html setup and css. Ideally in a snippet (Ctrl+M)
If case you have not yet done so, also make sure to check out the developer features of your browser. (F12 in most cases), with this you can inspect your html and change CSS to try things out. Comparing to other sources can help a lot to, see: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/jumbotron/ (And press F12 to inspect)

Comment: can you share your complete code